# No wifi adapter after installing fresh Ubuntu 20.04 over Windows 10

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

I saw many had the same question, but couldn't solve it yet. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop. Previously it was Windows 10. While installing I checked on the icon which asks to install third-party adapters, wifi. But after installing the OS, the wifi icon is not displayed, and in settings, it says "no wifi adapter found". How to fix this issue?

My machine is an HP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wireless not working after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4612/wireless-not-working-after-installation)

Comment: @vipulpetkar it did not worked

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.